# How to connect database with R

Tags: sql, r, database

I have a problem using sqlQuery to connect database with R.

```
library(RODBC)
res =sqlQuery(channel,
    paste0("select pb.col1,pb.col2 from pb,
                   mp,fb,st 
            where fb.col10 in ('%s',input), 
            and fb.col20=mp.col30 
            and pb.col40=st.col50 
            and pb.col45=st.col60 
            and mp.col40=pb.col80 and 
            pb.col80=st.col90"),
         believeNRows=F)
```

Here, `input=c("abc","def","wvy","etz")`, but the real input has more than 10,000 string elements.

Channel is already set up for connecting with the database.

It looks like there are some problems with where-clause but I do not know how to fix it.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what error message do you get? can you connect to your database at all? does a simple query work (e.g. `SELECT * FROM your_database`)?

Comment: yes, I run in SQL client with sql query and it works. I can connect to database after testing a simple query. error:  "42000 27 ERROR: "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect

Comment: I modify my code based on the following discussion but still have problem: sqlQuery(channel,sprintf("select pb.M,pb.P,pb.B,pb.BR,pb.SA,st.TO from pb INNER JOIN mp on mp.M=pb.M INNER JOIN fb on fb.F=mp.in INNER JOIN st on pb.M=st.M and pb.P=st.P and pb.S=st.S where fb.s in '%s'",paste0(input,collapse="','")))

Comment: Another issue is if input is not vector, but a dataframe, how to write the SQL query in R? Thanks;

Comment: the following code with a specified input works:`sprintf("select pb.col1,pb.col2 
         from pb,mp,fb,st 
            where fb.col10 in ('abc','def')
            and fb.col20=mp.col30 
            and pb.col40=st.col50 
            and pb.col45=st.col60 
            and mp.col40=pb.col80 and 
            pb.col80=st.col90")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste0` does not work the way you are using it.  You would need to use:

```
sprintf("select pb.col1,pb.col2 
         from pb,mp,fb,st 
            where fb.col10 in %s 
            and fb.col20=mp.col30 
            and pb.col40=st.col50 
            and pb.col45=st.col60 
            and mp.col40=pb.col80 and 
            pb.col80=st.col90", input)
```

Next, the way you have this structured will result in the `query` argument being a vector. You should aim to have `query` be a single string.

You might be better off using `RODBCext`

```
library(RODBCext)
res =sqlExecute(channel,
              "select pb.col1,pb.col2 
               from pb,mp,fb,st 
               where fb.col10 in ?, 
                  and fb.col20=mp.col30 
                  and pb.col40=st.col50 
                  and pb.col45=st.col60 
                  and mp.col40=pb.col80 
                  and pb.col80=st.col90",
              data = list(c("abc", "def", "wvy", "etz")),
              fetch = TRUE,
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Lastly, I'm not sure this query is valid SQL syntax.  Maybe I'm mistaken, but I don't think you can list multiple tables in the `FROM` clause like you have here.  If you need multiple tables, there should be some way of joining them.

```
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.Ref
```

EDIT: I just saw that your `input` has over 10,000 elements, which will make `sqlExecute` pretty slow.  Are you sure a `LIKE` is the best way to query these data.  If possible, I would recommend some other approach to isolating the data that you need.

Comment: I have tried using sprintf and rewrite my SQL with INNer Join but still does not work:

Comment: My code is: sqlQuery(channel,sprintf("select pb.M,pb.P,pb.B,pb.BR,pb.SA,st.TO from pb INNER JOIN mp on mp.M=pb.M INNER JOIN fb on fb.F=mp.in INNER JOIN st on pb.M=st.M and pb.P=st.P and pb.S=st.S where fb.s in %s",input))

Comment: the purpose of using these multi table with inner join is to test R's capacity to obtain data from 1TB Netezza database which is not relational DB. I want to see how much time needed if using the most complicated query when processing 10,000 input or more in future. Thanks;

Comment: Your code will result in an error when you have `WHERE fb.s IN abc, def` etc.  Which is why the `sqlExecute` syntax would be preferable.  The other option is to use SQL injection, which has security issues.

Comment: My best recommendation would be to use a SQL client to test your query.  Once you have a working query in the SQL client, then you can adapt it to R.  I often find developing complex queries in R to be challenging.

Comment: And my previous SQL syntax works fine in Agenity workbench so SQL query should be OK but not interpretated well when just copy it into R.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. Actually, that is what I have done. I ensure my complex query works then put it into R. But looks like something is wrong here. e.g. I check my input=c("abc","def"..) while in SQL client I type where fb.s in ('abc','dfe') and it works. Not sure whether " and ' matters.

Comment: Good.  now that we know your query works, the adaptation is probably failing at the `IN`.  When you insert your `input` vector, you are creating the string  `WHERE fb.s IN abc, def`.  You need that to become `WHERE fb.s IN ('abc', 'def')`.  The `sqlExecute` code I provided in the answer might make this easier, and prevent the use of SQL injection.  Otherwise, you'll need to put `sprintf("'%s'", paste0(input, collapse = "', '"))` in place of `input`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ben! Could you please paste the complete sqlExecute code and sprintf code here? I hope to avoid any tiny problem.

Comment: I edited my answer.  That should do it (except for fixing the WHERE clause, but that part you have down).

Comment: I have tried sqlExecute by using a 4 elements input: list(c("abc", "def", "wvy", "etz")) but get following error: Error in sqlPrepare(channel, query, errors) : [RODBCext] Error: SQLPrepare failed
In addition: Warning message:
In sqlPrepare(channel, query, errors) :
  42000 27 ERROR:

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: OK, I find out my problem should add ('%s') then work. thanks!